# System requirements for installing kubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation

What are the minimum system requirements for installing kubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: Google it! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to google it to know more.

```
Desktop & laptop
```

Required

Processor   1 GHz (x86)

Memory  512MB

Hard drive capacity 4GB

Video card  VGA @ 640×480

Recommended

Processor Better than 1 GHz (x86)

Memory   1 GB

Hard drive capacity   10 GB

Video Card VGA @ 1024×768

follow this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu#System_requirements